# How to set a constraint layout width of an item in a recyclerview to a percentage of the parents width, not a fixed dp value?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with recyclerview items width:
i already looked through android docs and stack so i think, there is no solution to this problem.

i have an ordinary recyclerview with a horizontal gridlayout

sorry, but i dont have enough reputation to embed pictures

[Picture of recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEJdj.png)

and i want the items of it being shown next to each other, but I want to make the width of the items depend on the width of the parent (in this case, the recyclerview width used in the other fragment).
I can show you what i want by using a fixed value (in this example 200dp)

[Picture of the solution I want, but here a fixed value for width is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tpz6v.png)

However if my constraint of the item is set to "match parent" like here:

[Picture constraint set to match parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz3e6.png)

The result is, that the width of the items seen in the phone always depends of the width of the recyclerview. in my case its cut nearly in half:
[recyclerview cut in half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1dhm.png)

also android studio only allows one view as a top level layout, so i cannot use a guideline that is set to any %

[possible solution to that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1WH8.png)

Comment: can't we use gridlayout manager in this case ????

Comment: Can you provide xml files of your layouts? Both your constraint layout containing your recyclerview and your recyclerview item layout. Please edit your question and add them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have width of recycler view (in pixel not dp), just divide it by number of items in a row, and in your adapter in "onBindViewHolder" method set item width. this solution is when all of your item has same width.

In addition for height of every item use `WRAP_CONTENT`.